# Using a loop to simplify preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, simplify

Am I able to simplify this code? I am getting five strings from a `SELECT` query, stripping them down to only numbers and adding them.

```
$sum = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$row['AB']) + preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$row['CD']) + preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$row['EF']) + preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$row['GH']) + preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$row['IJ']);
```

Can I do something like this:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$sum = $row['AB'] + $row['CD'] + $row['EF'] + $row['GH'] + $row['IJ']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple loop to reduce code duplication:

Provided your sql only selects the required columns:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($row as $item)
    $sum += preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$item);
```

If you have more columns in the row (and you actually need that data so you cant just alter the SQL):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach(['AB','CD','EF','GH','IJ'] as $key)
    $sum += preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$row[$key]);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll accept your answer when the wait is up :)

Comment: No problem. As a side note, if you have to run the code frequantly (eg not just a weekly report of something) then i would refactor the database to include the required data in integar columns, so you can do the math in SQL its self